# Error when using my ccspriteframes class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i wanted to have already loaded frames for my bullet sprites so I made a class that will hold all of the sprite frames. When I use this class it crashes. I could really use the help, thank you a lot.

.h

```
@interface loadedFrames : NSObject 
{
    CCSpriteFrame *bullet0;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSpriteFrame *bullet0;
@end
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer <GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate, GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>
{
    loadedFrames *frames;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) loadedFrames *frames;
```

.m

```
@implementation loadedFrames : NSObject
@synthesize bullet0;
@end

- (void) loadSprites
{
      [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"clonespritesheet%d.plist", loadlevel]];

      self.frames.bullet0 = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
               spriteFrameByName:@"bullet0.png"];
}

- (void) addBullet:(int)bulletType
{
      mainbullet = [bullet spriteWithSpriteFrame:frames.bullet0];
}
```

crashlog

```
2013-04-01 01:45:42.596 test[15111:907] *** Assertion failure in -[bullet initWithSpriteFrame:], /Users/Fei/Desktop/test/libs/cocos2d/CCSprite.m:212
(lldb)
```

Comment: when you have crash, there is always crashlog in the console. add this crashlog to your question.

Comment: so, as you can see, assertion failure occures in the line 212 of CCSprite.m file. look at this assertion and you will find message and reason of crash.

Comment: tip: enable global exception breakpoint in xcode, this will stop the app and show the line causing the exception